# Python Parser-Regular Expression

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I have two strings in Python:

```
String1 = "1.451E1^^http://www.test.org/Schema#double"
String2 = "http://www.test.org/m3-lite#AirTemperature"
```

From String1 i want to extract the number **1.451E1** meaning the field from the start of the string till the ^ symbol.

From String2 i want to extract field **AirTemperature** meaning the field from the # symbol and after till the end of the string.
Can anyone help me with the the regular expressions for the parser?

Comment: a simple use of split function will be enough. No need of regular expression ASFAIK seeing your case

Comment: I didnt know about the split function.I am new to python.I followed the advice of  Arpit Solanki : print(str.split('^^')[0]),print(str.split('#')[1]) for each case and it worked.Thanks guys.

Answer (score 3):

If your strings have such clear separators, maybe a simple `split` is enough?

```
value = string.split("^^")[0]
measurement = string.split("#")[-1]
```

If regular expressions are really what you want, `^([0-9E.]+)\^` and `#(\w+)$` are an ok start.